# Is it possible to make the dropdownlist inside the gridview to be the parameter of the other dropdownlist inside the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, parameters

I am creating a gridview with 2 columns named ARTICLE and COLOR. But my problem is that the article is the parameter of color. but i dont know how to make it the parameter.

.aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvIMF" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        onrowcommand="dgvIMF_RowCommand" onrowdatabound="dgvIMF_RowDataBound" 
        DataKeyNames="ArtNo">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Article">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlArt" runat="server" DataTextField="ArticleNo" DataValueField="ArticleNo" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Color">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColor" runat="server" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Description" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aspnetdbConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT SUBDETAILS.Description FROM PRICESIZESET INNER JOIN SIZESET ON PRICESIZESET.SizePriceID = SIZESET.SizeSetID INNER JOIN ARTICLE AS ARTICLE ON ARTICLE.ControlNo = PRICESIZESET.ControlNo INNER JOIN ARTICLEFABRICASSIGN AS ARTICLEFABRICASSIGN ON ARTICLEFABRICASSIGN.ControlNo = ARTICLE.ControlNo INNER JOIN FABRIC AS FABRIC ON FABRIC.FabricID = ARTICLEFABRICASSIGN.FabricID INNER JOIN SUBDETAILS AS SUBDETAILS ON SUBDETAILS.SubDetailsID = FABRIC.ColorID WHERE (ARTICLE.BrandID = @artno)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dgvIMF" Name="artno" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aspnetdbConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT ARTICLE.ArticleNo FROM PRICESIZESET INNER JOIN SIZESET ON PRICESIZESET.SizePriceID = SIZESET.SizeSetID INNER JOIN ARTICLE AS ARTICLE ON ARTICLE.ControlNo = PRICESIZESET.ControlNo INNER JOIN ARTICLEFABRICASSIGN AS ARTICLEFABRICASSIGN ON ARTICLEFABRICASSIGN.ControlNo = ARTICLE.ControlNo INNER JOIN FABRIC AS FABRIC ON FABRIC.FabricID = ARTICLEFABRICASSIGN.FabricID INNER JOIN SUBDETAILS AS SUBDETAILS ON SUBDETAILS.SubDetailsID = FABRIC.ColorID WHERE ARTICLE.ArticleNo = @brand">

        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlBrand" Name="brand" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Can you post your gridview code so far.

Comment: im having an error in the select parameter in my sqldatasource2. that is where i want to put my parameter that im talking about